# Jquery - How do I change my classes in per click

Tags: jquery

I want to change my button classes when users clicked "share" button. For that, I'm using `toggleClasses()`method.

But when I tried, it gives me only last class. Where do I mistake and how can I fix that ?

```
$('#fb_button').each(function () {
        var count = 0;
        var thisButton = $(this);
        thisButton.click(function () {
            count++;
            thisButton.val("Share" + '(' + count + ')');
            thisButton.toggleClass('green-button blue-button red-button')
        })

})
```

Comment: `count` will **always** be zero in this code. Also having buttons with the same id is invalid syntax so your selector won't work correctly either

Comment: `$.fn.toggleClass()` doesn't work as you seem to expect it. It won't put the green, then the blue and then the red

Comment: then what I need to do ?

Comment: What do you mean with "having buttons with the same id" ? I have just one button.

Comment: @cervantes You should better explain what is your expected behaviour instead of posting not working code without real explanaition of what you are looking for

Comment: @cervantes Because you use an `each` loop i guess...

Comment: Mr. @A.Wolff as I said " I want to change my button's classes " and sory for awful explanation, I am new in jquery

Comment: @cervantes But you want on first click the button to get green class, then blue one, then red, then green again, then etc... Or what? Your code doesn't really make sense so we cannot devine what you are looking for...

Comment: please add html part too for more clarification. Add that in your question

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh, in html part, there is a just button, no need to add.

Comment: what you want actually?

Comment: @A.Wolff I see, I thought if I use toggleClass(),  I can display these class in every click

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh I want to change button class, when someone click the share button

Comment: every time new class or only toggle between two classes?

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh toggle between three classes

Comment: @cervantes Does this button have one of these classes by default or none?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like below:-

```js
var array = ['green-button', 'blue-button', 'red-button'];
var count = 0;
$('#fb_button').click(function () {
  if(count==3){
    count = 0;
  }
  $(this).removeClass().addClass(array[count]);
 count++;
});
```

```css
.green-button{
  background:green;
}

.blue-button{
  background:blue;
}

.red-button{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="fb_button">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: @cervantes  glad to help you

Comment: I want to upvote your answer too but.. it seems I have no permission for that

Comment: Ya your code is working but this imply the button cannot get any other class than the ones you want to toggle